# Mailto works in Flash Pro but not when Published

Tags: actionscript-3, mailto

Code is working when testing in Adobe Flash Pro as expected (email application opens and includes subject, name, id, supervisor, score), however whenever I publish and open in either FireFox, IE, or just open the swf player, the email client will open but with all the fields missing including the subject... I love how it works in Flash, and the simplicity of not having to have a server side php, but its not working as expected...

```
stop();

import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.net.URLLoader;


// Variables
nameout_txt.text = names;
idout_txt.text = id;
supervisorout_txt.text = supervisor;
score.text = myscore+"";

//Email
var Email:URLRequest = new URLRequest
("mailto:ra@email.org" + "?subject=WOE Certificate" + "   " + names +    "&body=" + "Name: " + names + "\nEID: " 
 +id + "\nSupervisor Name: "+ supervisor + "\nScore: " + myscore);
emailbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,emailCert);

function emailCert(event:MouseEvent):void {
navigateToURL(Email," _blank" ) ;
}


//Array to hold a list of the weekdays.
var weekdays:Array = new Array ("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
"Thursday","Friday","Saturday");

//Array to hold a list of the months.
var months:Array = new Array ("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul",
"Aug", "Sep", "Oct","Nov","Dec");

//Adds an event listener to the dymanic text field.
the_date_txt.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,showDate);

function showDate(event:Event):void {
//Create a new instance of the date class.
var myDate:Date = new Date();

//Retrieve the day, month and year from the date class.
var theDay=weekdays[myDate.getDay()];
var theMonth=months[myDate.getMonth()];
var theDate=myDate.getDate();
var theYear=myDate.getFullYear();

//Display the date in the dynamic text field.
the_date_txt.text=theDay+", "+theMonth+" "+theDate+", "+theYear;
}

/* Printing... */
/* Button */


print_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,    fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_3);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndPlay(14);
}
trace(myscore)
```

[Working Correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fVr6.png)
[Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HFOW.png)

Comment: are you opening the .swf file locally (e.g. ```file:///path/to/your.swf.```) or served from a local webserver ? (e.g. ```http://localhost/your.swf```) ?

Comment: I am opening from the folder. I have tried both the .swf file, and the .html, and neither one will populate the fields as it does with Ctrl+Enter in Flash Pro...

Comment: Can you export a projector(.exe) from Flash Player ?

Comment: I created a .exe, however my "email button" will not even open the email client

Comment: In works in exe form! (that will do for now... until I can get access to web based and begin testing from there. Thank you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a security constraint on Flash Player and you have multiple options:

1. If you want to run the swf file locally you can add an exception in the [Global Security Settings Panel](https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html)
2. On Windows, export an .exe projector file using Flash Player.exe
3. Use a local webserver (like [XAMP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)) and load the file from `http://localhost` instead of using the `file:///` path (or simply upload the .swf file to a website and access if from there)
4. Publish your file for [AIR](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/air.html) instead of Flash Player

For option 1, you would need to add this exception for every computer you plan to run this .swf locally, therefore option 2 would make more sense.

Option 3 should also be simple enough.

Option 4 may be overkill, unless you need access to nicer native functionalities (like file system access, saving settings, custom icon, minimizing app to systray and potentially publishing to IOS/Android/etc.)

Comment: The .exe option works right now but I am running into 2 problems.
First, this is the flow of the project...
User is greeted with a screen asking for name, Id, and Supervisor name
Next a 4 minute training video is shown
Then the user is given a 10 question scored quiz
If 70%+ is achieved, they are presented with a certificate and 2 buttons, 1 "Email" and 1 "Print" 
As of right now, everything "works" however I have identified 2 problems

Comment: 1) the video has to accompany the .exe (or .swf) so I may look at creating the training portion in flash as well (although I don't know how easy that will be)
2) I will need the email option when this is placed on the districts web portal, page, site, wherever it is deployed. The exe is nice, but the fact that it has to have the video with it, and the size of the video kind of causes a problem. Is there not a way to fully embed the video?

Comment: Would it be easier to place the mp4 on the server, and then link that video in the swf file. Would the swf or an exe accessed on a machine with internet access still be able to successfully play said video?

Comment: That's a totally separate question, however, if you're using the Flash IDE you should be able to embed a video in the timeline. It has it's limitations, be sure to checkout what those are to ensure everything will work with your project requirements. Good luck! Feel free to vote/mark the answer if was helpful ;)

Comment: Done and done, I will create a seperate question when I get to that point thank you